# Is there any way to change the background color activity through java file in android?

Tags: android

I try to change the background color  activity through java file but it does not work

so,

Is there are any way to change the background color through java file (Not throw  XML file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background of `Activity` from code using a `Drawable`

Set a `Drawable` from Resource like this

```
 getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_bg);
```

Or set a `Color` like this

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in code you can do this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.blahblah);
ll.setBackgroundColor(R.color.FireBrick);
```

The java code above is equivalent to placing this xml attribute inside your layout:

```
android:background="@color/FireBrick"
```

To make it easier on you, I recommend you placing this [color.xml](https://github.com/wtsang02/colors/blob/master/color.xml) file inside your `res/values/` folder. The FireBrick color is defined inside that particular file.